# Inappropriate Fan Control on Asus Laptop Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: laptop, asus, fan, overheating, temperature

My Asus laptop running Ubuntu 20.10 constantly overheats and does not appropriately increase the fan speed to accommodate. When searching to see if there was a way I could manually control the fans, I found that lm-sensors was not able to control the fan, as there were no detected fans that could be controlled by it.

How could I control the fans?

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the fans form an OS if hardware doesn't allow this.

Most likely your laptop needs cleaning.

Comment: The fan has been cleaned already, the fan doesn't physically go higher when it needs to.